# CONCATENAR DOS REGISTROS EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Necesito concatenar dos registros de dos tablas separados por un "-" en mi SQL SERVER.
Esta es la consulta que hice para concatenar PTA y ORD:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MIN(CO.PTA), + '-' + MIN(CO.ORD))"Orden",CP.PRF"Matricula", CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), CP.NOM)"Nombre",ISNULL( CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CP.FCG,103)), '') "Fecha de Carga"
FROM dbo.CLIORD CO
JOIN dbo.CLIPRF CP ON CO.PRC = CP.PRF
JOIN dbo.CLIPCI PRO ON PRO.PCI = CP.JUR
WHERE CP.FCG >= '1/10/2018'
AND CO.OPA IN ('A','B','D','J','P','C') 
AND (ESP_TBL IS NULL OR MAI_FAC IS NULL OR CP.TXT IS NULL)
AND CP.PRF NOT IN ('M','SM')
GROUP BY CP.PRF, CP.NOM, CP.FCG,  PRO.DES 
ORDER BY MIN(CO.PTA), MIN(CO.ORD), CP.PRF
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
> specified.

Comment: Saludos. Revisa tu SQL, Después del primer CONCAT, a continuación del MIN(CO.PTA) tienes una coma ",".

Comment: Gracias! pero le saqué la coma y me dice el error siguiente: The concat function requires 2 to 254 arguments.

Comment: Lo siento; me equivoque debe ser CONCAT (MIN(CO.PTA), '-' + MIN(CO.ORD)) no es la coma es el signo más "+". Lo que parece indicar es que tu ORDER BY MIN(CO.PTA), MIN(CO.ORD), CP.PRF debe ser ORDER BY CONCAT (MIN(CO.PTA), '-' + MIN(CO.ORD)), CP.PRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al principio tienes un error de concepto en la función concat.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MIN(CO.PTA), + '-' + MIN(CO.ORD))"Orden"
```

Debe de ser

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MIN(CO.PTA), '-' , MIN(CO.ORD)) As "Orden"
```

> dos registros de dos tablas separados por un "-" en

Concat se encarga de anexar esos valores, utilizando como separador la coma. Es casi igual que el operador +, pero con algunas sutiles diferencias.

Y el order by, se puede entender de dos maneras.

```
declare @table table (pta int, ord int, fecha date)
insert into @table (pta, ord, fecha)
values
(100,200,'20200101'),
(125,201,'20200101'),
(130,200,'20200102'),
(117,203,'20200101'),
(98,210,'20200102'),
(140,205,'20200101'),
(155,197,'20200101'),
(160,125,'20200102'),
(104,209,'20200101');

SELECT CONCAT(MIN(T.PTA),'-',MIN(T.ORD)) AS "ORDEN",
FECHA

FROM @table T
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY "ORDEN",fecha
```

Si el resultado a obtener en este caso es, que quiero ordenar por el valor concatenado de las funciones min(pta) más el guión más la función min(ord) como una sola cadena, y luego la columna fecha, puedo simplemente realizar un order by por el alias de la columna.

[image: Resultado]

Ahora bien, si lo que deseo obtener es el ordenamiento, primero por el valor resultante de la función min(pta), luego por min(ord), y luego por fecha, entonces:

```
declare @table table (pta int, ord int, fecha date)
insert into @table (pta, ord, fecha)
values
(100,200,'20200101'),
(125,201,'20200101'),
(130,200,'20200102'),
(117,203,'20200101'),
(98,210,'20200102'),
(140,205,'20200101'),
(155,197,'20200101'),
(160,125,'20200102'),
(104,209,'20200101');

SELECT CONCAT(MIN(T.PTA),'-',MIN(T.ORD)) AS "ORDEN",
FECHA

FROM @table T
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY MIN(T.PTA),MIN(T.ORD),fecha
```

[image: Resultado2]

[Concatenar cadenas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/02/sql-server-concatenar-cadenas/)

[Order by](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)